# returning the value from model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just want to get user_id from my database and set it to the session via Codeigniter. The problem is that when I print session I can see the following result:

```
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
   (
     [user_id] => 5
   )
)
```

instead of this one:

```
 [user_id] => 5
```

Can you help me to return the value from model so that the problem will not occur.

Here is my model:

```
public function get_user_id() {

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');   
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));      
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {      
    return $query->result();
    }
    else{
     return false;
    }       
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
$user_id = $this->model_users->get_user_id();
$data = array (     
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'logged_in' => 1        
              );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, `row()` instead `result()` since you just wants to retrieve one row.

```
public function get_user_id() {

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');   
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));      
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $row= $query->row();
        return $row->user_id;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Check [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) to get complete list of available functions to fetch rows from query result.

**Note**

Just for your information, you should read parameters (GET, POST) in controller and pass to model functions.

So, your complete code would be identical to following:

*Controller*

```
$email=$this->input->post('email');
$user_id = $this->model_users->get_user_id($email);
$data = array (     
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'logged_in' => 1        
        );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

*Model*

```
public function get_user_id($email) {

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');   
    $this->db->where('email',$email);      
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $row= $query->row();
        return $row->user_id;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Glad that helped you. Voteup/Accept answer. If its solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is other way to show the result except row(), you can use result_array(). it generate array result.

```
public function get_user_id() {

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');   
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));      
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $row= $query->result_array();
        return $row['user_id'];
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }       
}
```

for more information, see here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html